# RactiveJS: Filtering DIV elements based on text input value

Tags: ractivejs

I've been trying to find an example on how to filter a container of divs based on a search text box using RactiveJS.

I know how to get the key pressed events using Ractive but unsure on how to filter the model the RactiveJS way. Keeping copies / history of the data during key press event seems like a bad idea. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can let Ractive manage it (http://jsfiddle.net/nnbww/):

```
<div id="container">
  <input name="search" type="text" value="{{searchTerm}}"/>
  {{#items}}
     {{#(..indexOf(searchTerm)===0)}}
         <div>{{.}}</div>
     {{/}}
 {{/items}}
</div>
```

You can use `this` instead of `.` if you prefer:

```
{{# this.indexOf(searchTerm)===0 }}
```

And put the function on your data, rather than inline:

```
{{# filter(this) }}
```

This would allow you to change the filter as well. Check out http://examples.ractivejs.org/todos for a good example of this.

If you need to track other info about the filtered list (for example display a count of matched items), it's a bit more difficult to use a purely reactive approach (see version /1/ of above jsfiddle), which probably makes it simpler to use an observer:

```
 <input name="search" type="text" value="{{searchTerm}}"/>
 {{#filtered}}
     <div>{{.}}</div>
 {{/filtered}}
 Matching {{filtered.length}} of {{items.length}}
```

set in complete method:

```
var ractive = new Ractive({
    el: 'container',
    template: '#container',
    data: { 
        searchTerm: 'foo',
        items: [ 'foo', 'bar', 'biz', 'bah' ]
    },
    complete: function(){
        var r = this
        r.observe('searchTerm', function(search){
            var filtered = r.get('items').filter(function(item){
                return item.indexOf(search)===0
            })
            r.set('filtered', filtered)
        })
    }
})
```

(see version /2/ of jsfiddle link)

Answer (score 0):

If your searchable div's are static, then you can put an observer on your search term:
http://jsfiddle.net/fLd86/10/

```
ractive = new Ractive({
el: 'container',
template: '#container',
data: { searchTerm: 'foo' }
});

observer = ractive.observe( 'searchTerm', function ( newValue, oldValue, keypath ) {
    $( 'div.searchable:contains("' + newValue +'")').show();
    $( 'div.searchable:not(:contains("' + newValue +'"))').hide();
});
```

If the divs are part of your model, you'll need to put something in the template to inject them into the html, but the same sort of logic should work.